# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper in IntelliJ after upgrading to Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jackson, java-11

After upgrading to Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.2.6 / Jackson 2.10.3 I can't start my Application in Intellij. Running it with `java -jar app.jar` after compiling with maven it works just fine.

When trying to run in IntelliJ though, I get the following error: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`

Here is the full Stacktrace:

```
2020-04-28 13:07:36.079 ERROR 83492 --- [lication Thread] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6adede5]
2020-04-28 13:07:36.092  INFO 83492 --- [lication Thread] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-04-28 13:07:36.099 ERROR 83492 --- [lication Thread] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during stop

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6adede5]
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:53)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.tomcat.embed.core@9.0.33/org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:468)
    at spring.boot@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:107)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6adede5]
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configurationPropertiesReportEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/context/properties/ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6adede5]
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at spring.boot.actuator@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:143)
    at spring.boot.actuator@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:133)
    at spring.boot.actuator@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:122)
    at spring.boot.actuator@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:116)
    at spring.boot.actuator.autoconfigure@2.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.servletEndpointRegistrar(ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.java:65)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesReportEndpoint] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@6adede5]
    at spring.core@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
    at spring.core@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:232)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:210)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:149)
    at spring.context@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at spring.beans@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:569)
    ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3167)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2310)
    at spring.core@5.2.5.RELEASE/org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 87 more
Exception in Application stop method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application stop method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:905)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui/de.company.project.MyMainClass.stop(MyMainClass.java:87)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$10(LauncherImpl.java:865)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application de.company.project.MyMainClass
```

Here are my dependecies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I already tried removing the Jackson dependency but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `<scope>compile</scope>` in my jackson dependency was missing.
It works like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I also had to add `classmate` with the same scope:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
        <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Finally, I had to add both entries to my **module-info.java** files:

```
open module gui {
    ...
    requires com.fasterxml.classmate;
}
```

and

```
module core_entity {

    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
    ...

}
```

note the additional `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` requirement despite not having this explicit maven dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is simple. You are generating a jar from your code but issue is that when creating jar like that, you need to take care of providing your 3rd party dependencies in CLASSPATH, else above error might be thrown if while executing your jar, it doesn't find required external classes.

Now let's see 2 ways you described above:

1. `java -jar app.jar` this will package your current code along and needs proper files added to CLASSPATH.
2. Now when you generate jar through maven, it downloads 3rd party required classes and then packages your app in jar which will have before mentioned downloaded classes along. So while running that jar, all required classes will be present.

Comment: Sorry, it is not really clear why the error occurs. It happens after upgrading to Java 11 and *only* when running in IntelliJ. So how can I get IntelliJ to recognize my 3rd party classes via maven?